# FFmpeg zoom and pan with video as input

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have searched for all kind of ways how to get the zoompan filter to work on a video, I have not problems on a image:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i thumbnail_56138ba980d73.png -vf "zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,10)':d=125" -c:v mpeg2video -t 5 -s "796x450" test2.mpeg
```

That works just fine, I get a nice zoom on the picture. But when I then try to do the same where the input is a video:

```
ffmpeg -i tmpFile_149712.mp4 -vf "zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,10)':d=150" -c:v mpeg2video -t 5 -s "796x450" test2.mpeg
```

Then it gives me the follow output, and no video because of the aborted by core in the end. So that leads me to think if this filter even works with a video ?

Especially when I read the documentation for zoompan parameter -D *"This sets for how many number of frames effect will last for **single input image**."*

```
$ ffmpeg -i tmpFile_149712.mp4 -vf "zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,10)':d=150" -c:v mpeg2video -t 5 -s "796x450" test2.mpeg
ffmpeg version N-73887-g99ad832 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/vagrant/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/home/vagrant/ffmpeg_build    /include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/vagrant/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/home/vagrant/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable    -libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264
  libavutil      54. 28.100 / 54. 28.100
  libavcodec     56. 50.101 / 56. 50.101
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 25.100 /  5. 25.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'tmpFile_149712.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:00:12.10, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 359 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 356 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60     tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
[mpeg @ 0x2c17020] VBV buffer size not set, using default size of 130KB
If you want the mpeg file to be compliant to some specification
Like DVD, VCD or others, make sure you set the correct buffer size
Output #0, mpeg, to 'test2.mpeg':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg2video, yuv420p, 796x450, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 90k tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc56.50.101 mpeg2video
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mpeg2video (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[output stream 0:0 @ 0x2c12000] 100 buffers queued in output stream 0:0, something may be wrong.
Past duration 0.998039 too large
*** Error in `ffmpeg': corrupted double-linked list: 0x00000000030af400 ***bits/s dup=0 drop=17100
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Try with latest FFmpeg release, 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works by updating to lastest release. Tried with 3.0.2

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug in your version of FFMpeg. The newer version seems to work, but there is another issue. When you pass a video as an input for zoompan it first splits it into separate frames and then applies zoom/pan effect the each frame separately. So you get 125 (d=125 by default) output frames per each of your input video frame. I couldn't find a way how to work this around